# assigning array previous objects to next element and updating the last

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need that my application needs to place objects from previous to next element and update the last.

I tried just to assign but it can be wrong way because it doesn't work - the values are trashes

```
let coordinate=[{x:4, y:3} ,{x:4, y:4},{x:4, y:5},{x:4, y:6}];

for(let i=0;i<coordinate.length-2;++i){
   coordinate[i]=coordinate[i+1];
}
++coordinate[coordinate.length-1].y;
console.log(coordinate);
```

I think it is logically correct but maybe the way I am updating it is wrong?

Comment: yes it is the same object after it's operation. But lastly the last element need to be updated to new value.

Comment: your code only copies [1] => [0] and [2] => [1] ... doesn't touch [2]

Comment: does [this code](https://pastebin.com/CF5Be5tM) do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this right you want to do something like this:
Remove the first element and then push a new element that is an updated version of the last one.

```js
let coordinate=[{x:4, y:3} ,{x:4, y:4},{x:4, y:5},{x:4, y:6}];
coordinate.shift();
const lastElm = coordinate[coordinate.length - 1];
coordinate.push({
  ...lastElm,
  y: lastElm.y + 1
});
console.log(coordinate);
```

Comment: why my way is not proper?

Comment: @tekblade The iteration's condition is `i < coordinate.length-2` which means that the previous to last element is not updated, try to change it to `i < coordinate.length-1` or `i <= coordinate.length-2`

Comment: Tried. didn't work until: coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);